# Can't seem to hide textBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have fiddled around with C# quite a bit in the sense of making a webapp, however i decided i wanted to learn a bit more and ordered the book "Head First C#" fourth edition.

One of the first chapters guides you through making a matchup game but i'm getting stuck hiding the Emojis / textbox, they just stay visible when i launch.

Here's the C# code :

```
TextBlock lastTextBlockClicked;
    bool findingMatch = false;
    private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        if (findingMatch == false)
        {
            textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            lastTextBlockClicked = textBlock;
            findingMatch = true;
        }
        else if (textBlock.Text == lastTextBlockClicked.Text)
        {
            textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            findingMatch = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lastTextBlockClicked.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            findingMatch = false;
        }
    }
```

And here's the XAML code.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Text="?" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" IsEnabled="False" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
```

It's probably something extremely easy that i'm just overlooking but i've been trying for a while now.

Hope i can get some help from anyone, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your code is called when you push the left button on the TextBlock? The code looks correct. Try to place a breakpoint at the beginning of the method

Answer (score 1):

When `TextBlock` is disabled ==  `TextBlock.IsEnabled="False"`, the event `MouseDown` will not work. Change the `IsEnabled="True"` and it should work.

Comment: This worked for me, though i also found deleting : TextBlock.IsEnabled="False"

all together works, dunno if it can cause for problems later down the road though. Either way thank you!